# Room. Как хранить динамические поля в бд?

Tags: android, kotlin, room

Столкнулся с такой проблемой...
Сервер может возвращать странный тип данных. Типа:

```
{
  "value":"val"
}
```

и

```
{
  "value":[
        "val1",
        "val2"
     ]
}
```

Как результат одного и того же запроса. Т.е. можно ожидать как String, так и String[]. 
TypeAdapter для Retrofit я написал. Но пока даже протестить не могу, из-за того, что не компилится проект, из-за ошибки

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it.

Ну все понятно почему. Нужно написать TypeConverter

Я пытаюсь реализовать такую схему:
Объект, который надо сохранить, содержит список объектов Question

```
@Entity(tableName = "surveys_table")
data class Survey(

        ...,
        @SerializedName("questions")
        var questions: List<Question>

)
```

Question - это интерфейс с набором полей:

```
interface Question {

    ...
    var value: Any

}
```

Этот интерфейс наследуют 2 объекта:

```
data class QuestionWithArrayValues(
        ...,
        val _value: List<String>?

) : Question


data class QuestionWithStringValues(

        ...,
        val _value: String?

) : Question
```

А вот собственно и сам адаптер, в котором я пытаюсь объяснить room как хранить объекты:

```
class QuestionsConverter{

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromQuestionsDbList(questions: List<Question>?): String? {
        if (questions == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        return try {
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithStringValues>>() { }.type
            gson.toJson(questions, type)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithArrayValues>>() { }.type
            gson.toJson(questions, type)
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toQuestionsDbList(questions: String?): List<Question>? {
        if (questions == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        return try {
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithStringValues>>() {}.type
            gson.fromJson<List<QuestionWithStringValues>>(questions, type)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<QuestionWithArrayValues>>() {}.type
            gson.fromJson<List<QuestionWithArrayValues>>(questions, type)
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и регистрируем конвертер:

```
@TypeConverters(QuestionsConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() ...
```

Но я продолжаю получать ошибку:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it.

Также пробовал вместо интерфейса `Question` использовать абстрактный класс.
Я не уверен что так вообще можно делать и есть ли какой либо выход из этой ситуации...

Comment: а здесь `fun fromQuestionsDbList(questions: List<Question>?): String?` и здесь `fun toQuestionsDbList(questions: String?): List<Question>` вы возвращаете результат конвертации? Где return ...?

Comment: маппите кривое апи (когда получаете объект, то превращаете его в list с одним объектом) в вашу модель данных. В вашей модели это будет list. Потом сохраняете, тут уже стандартный конвертер из листа в json, и костылей придумывать не надо

Comment: @virex-84    return try { ......

Comment: @Valgaal Да, это будет определенно лучше. Завтра попробую, отпишусь

Comment: Не видел такой конструкции. Я бы сделал как обычно. Попробуйте отловить то что у вас возвращается в своей IDE.

Comment: Если у вас может быть ситуация, что большой список  объектов, то Converter и json не помогут, в лучшем случае вы увидите долгую задержку при обратной конвертации, а если окажется большим, то вообще краш. То в такой ситуации я бы советовал использовать доп. таблицу.  Так что если объектов немного будет, то предложенный способ @Valgaal будет хорош

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский Спасибо за совет. Список там не большой. До 10 объектов.